# How would you retrieve message and optional attributes from PubSubIO?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a topic on PubSub, and I want to create a pipeline on dataflow that reads from the topic classifies them according to message data and further read the attribute key value pairs.
Is there a way to differentiate between the message and attributes after they have transformed to PCollection using the PubSubIO's read transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Dataflow's PubsubIO API doesn't currently handle metadata and attributes of the Pubsub messages. I cannot think of an easy workaround.

This is something we are looking to improve rather soon. This work is tracked as [BEAM-53](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-53). Please check there for the most recent status.

Comment: Thank you. That was pretty helpful.

Comment: In the latest Apache Beam PubSub IO you can get the attribute list of the message using getAttributeMap and getAttribute.  See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/PubsubIO.PubsubMessage.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-